# Prevent variable expansion in the parameter of a function to be expanded in a for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I am building a generic function `exec_all_dirs` in bashrc that would run a command in multiple directories.

```sh
function exec_all_dirs() {
  curdir=$PWD
  dirs=(
    ~/dir1
    ~/dir2
    ~/dir3
  )
  for dir in ${dirs[@]};
  do
    echo "---------- $dir ---------"
    "$@"                                                          # run the command here.
  done
  cd $curdir
}

function all_func() {
  exec_all_dirs 'cd $dir && another_func_defined_in_bashrc'       # how to pass $dir
}
function all_du() {
  exec_all_dirs 'du -sh $dir'
}
```

How can I pass `$dir` as argument to `exec_all_dirs` so it gets expanded in the for loop?

Comment: There are a number of quoting bugs here -- http://shellcheck.net/ will find them automatically.

Comment: Also, `function funcname() {` merges legacy ksh syntax (`function funcname {`) and POSIX sh syntax (`funcname() {`) in a way that's incompatible with _both_ legacy ksh and POSIX sh; use one or the other (the POSIX one if you care about compatibility with other modern shells), don't combine both. See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
exec_all_dirs(){
    local curdir=$PDW
    local cmd dir
    local dirs=(
        ~/dir1
        ~/dir2
        ~/dir3
    )
    for dir in ${dirs[@]}; do
        echo      "---------- $dir ---------"
        printf -v   cmd "$1" "$dir"
        bash   -c "$cmd"
    done
    cd $curdir
}

all_fu(){ exec_all_dirs 'cd %s && another_func_defined_in_bashrc'; }
all_du(){ exec_all_dirs 'du -sh %s'; }
```

Comment: Subshell, not being an interactive one, won't know about a function `another_func_defined_in_bashrc` defined in bashrc. Any way to work around that?

Comment: This solves my problem: https://superuser.com/a/1420612/768336. Though let me know if you find a better one. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Instead, consider a different approach, way safer and easier to use. Work just like `xargs` works. Allow passing the command, as-is separated by words, to your command. Then define the work in a separate function. that way you won't have to handle putting it all in single quotes. Pass variable context `"$dir"` as a positional argument to the command.

```
exec_all_dirs() {
  local curdir dirs
  curdir=$PWD
  dirs=(
    ~/dir1
    ~/dir2
    ~/dir3
  )
  for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    echo "---------- $dir ---------"
    "$@" "$dir"
  done
  cd $curdir
}

_all_func_in() {
   if cd "$1"; then
      another_func_defined_in_bashrc
   fi
}

all_func() {
  exec_all_dirs _all_func_in
}

all_du() {
  exec_all_dirs du -sh
}
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck. Do not use `function name()` - just `name()`.

---

> How can I pass $dir as argument to exec_all_dirs so it gets expanded in the for loop?

You can replace it yourself:

```
echo "$1" | sed 's/$dir/'"$dir"'/g'
```

You can just run `eval`:

```
eval "$@"
```

Comment: `sed 's/$dir/'"$dir"'/g'` is by no means safe in the general case. If `dir=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''`, doing simple string substitution is still going to result in something `eval` will actually run.

Comment: BTW, for `exec_all_dirs`, I'd tend to suggest putting `"$@" "$dir"` in a subshell; then you don't need the `cd` at the end at all, and you're isolating the functions from each other (you don't want the first call to leave the cwd in a location from which the second call in the loop will fail).

Comment: Also, `eval "$@"` has enough unwanted side effects that I'd generally require callers to pass only a single argument if the intent is to use `eval`, or at least to use `"$*"` instead to be explicit about the semantics. (Since `eval printf '%s\n' "first word" "second word"` becomes `eval printf %s\n first word second word`, implying that one still gets `"$@"`'s benefits of respecting word boundaries is misleading to the reader/reviewer of such code)

Comment: For different positions of the argument, I would have to create separate conditions which is not very flexible for a generic method. Thank you for answering.